# Obtener ruta completa de una imagen en local

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo un script php para el que necesito almacenar en una variable la ruta completa de una imagen guardada en local. No se si es posible con php o con javascript.

Un saludo

Comment: Puedes guardar y obtener la ruta de una imagen en una variable tanto en php como en javascript. La forma de guardarla para poder después recuperarla con facilidad dependerá de varias cosas. ¿Podrías dar más detalles en la pregunta de lo que quieres hacer, sistema operativo que usas y si la aplicación de php es una aplicación web o una aplicación standalone?

Comment: Utilizo linux con apache. Es una aplicación web. Quiero subir una imagen a twitter directamente desde php usando un formulario con un input file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

para obtener la ruta de la imagen, la cual guardarias en una variable, puedes hacer algo tal que asi, y ver la ruta en la que te guarda la imagen

```
$root= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$host= $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
$url= $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];    
$fileName=$_FILES["file"]["name"];

echo $root.$host.$url.$filename;
```